# insert an array as an object property (json)

Tags: php, json

I expect this result

```
[
    {
        "uId": "1",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "Bond",
        "task": [
            {
                "task": "teaching"
            },
            {
                "task": "tutoring"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

where result1 and result2 are the following:
$result1

```
[{"uId":"1","firstName":"James","lastName":"Bond"}]
```

$result2

```
[{"task":"teaching"},{"task":"tutoring"}]
```

I tried

```
$result1[0]['tabs'] = $result2;
echo json_encode($result1);
```

but it says Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: You mean `$result1[0]['task'] = $result2;` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do like this..

```
$result1='[{"uId":"1","firstName":"James","lastName":"Bond"}]';
$result2='[{"task":"teaching"},{"task":"tutoring"}]';
$arr1 = json_decode($result1,true);
$arr2 = json_decode($result2,true);
$arr1[0]['task'] = $arr2;
$finalJSON = json_encode($arr1);
echo $finalJSON;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
   [{"uId":"1","firstName":"James","lastName":"Bond","task":[{"task":"teaching"},{"task":"tutoring"}]}]
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/141495)</kbd>

Comment: The output is not I wanted, why there's a zero? Your output I can achieve with $result['task'] = $result2;

Comment: Nope , you were trying to access an object in the form of an array and that's why you got the FATAL error.

Comment: how to convert array to string?

Comment: You can use `implode` like this.. `echo implode(' ',$array);` but note it won't work on multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: I tried  $result1 = implode(' ',$result1);
 but can't

Comment: Can you post a new question and link me here? That didn't work because `$result` is a multidimensional one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284880/convert-array-that-contains-object-to-string

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51391/discussion-between-user3522457-and-shankar-damodaran)

Answer (score 0):

interesting. If the array format is always the same, you can use string functions to change the output too:

```
$str = '[{"uId":"1","firstName":"James","lastName":"Bond"}]';
$combined = (trim($str, '}]').',"tasks":[{"task":"teaching"},{"task":"tutoring"}]'.'}]');
```

Does not need to change into array.