# convert array that contains object to string

Tags: php, json

I got an error when I did  `$result1 = implode(' ',$result1)`

I use 2 query and wish to combine the result into one, here's my query:

```
if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
         $result1[] = $obj;
    }

}

if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($obj = $user->fetch_object()) {
         $result2[] = $obj;
    }

}
```

- convert **$result1 and result2** to string here
- I need **$result1 and result2** to be like

  `'[{
       "uId":"1",
       "firstName":"James",
       "lastName":"Bond"
    }]'`

so that it can run below code.

```
$arr1 = json_decode($result1,true);
$arr2 = json_decode($result2,true);
$arr1[0]['task'] = $arr2;
$finalJSON = json_encode($arr1);
echo $finalJSON;
```

Comment: Any time you mention that you got an error, please include the actual error you received. What was it?

Comment: [json_encode](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) ...

Comment: Why do you need to encode your object into json and decode it back to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result1` and `$result2` **are already arrays**.

Remove the below line:

```
$arr1 = json_decode($result1,true);
$arr2 = json_decode($result2,true);
```

And either change `fetch_object` to `fetch_array`,

or change `$arr1[0]['task'] = $arr2;` to `$arr1[0]->task = $arr2;` (*don't change both*).

Comment: Cannot use string offset as an array in  $result1[0]->task = $result2;

Comment: @user3522457 `$result1` should be an array at first, you only have to use `json_encode` at last....